# How to write unit test for subscribe callback of a service

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I am learning about how to write unit test in Angular. 
I create a httpService having method sendToServer. Every component uses it to send request to server:

```
sendToServer(method, url, body, header, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback?);
```

Here is my component

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpService) {
   }
   data ;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getToken();
  }

  getToken(){
    this.http.sendToServer("GET", "/api/tokent",{}, null, data=>{
      this.data = data;
    });
  }

}
```

Here is my unit test code:

```
it("should call getTokent and return data", fakeAsync(() => {
    const response = "abc";
    component.getToken();
    spyOn(service, 'sendToServer').and.returnValue(of(response));
    tick(); 

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.data).toEqual(response);
  }));
```

How can I test in callback function of http.senntoServer

Comment: With spying on the sendToServer call, the actual function is not being executed but instead just returns an observable which emits your response string immediately. So your callback is never executed. You probably could use ```spyOn(service, 'sendToServer').and.callFake(...)``` to actually trigger your callback function.

Comment: `spyOn(http, 'sendToServer').and.callFake(()=>{
     return of("data");     
    });
    guard1.getData();   
    console.log("Data",guard1.permissions);`
It cannot call to callback function.
`getData(){
    this.http.sendToServer("GET", API.ACCESS_PERMISSION, {}, null, data => {
      this.permissions = data;
      this.aa();
    })
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger your callback function inside the mocked DataService instead of returning a fixed value. Using `returnValue` just as the name suggests, returns the value if the method gets called and does nothing else.

In your case what you would want to use is `callFake`and inside that fake function you can then trigger your callback.

**component.spec.ts**

```
it('test callback', () => {
  spyOn(TestBed.get(DataService), 'sendToServer').and.callFake((parm1: string, param2: string, param3: any, param4: any, callback: (data) => {}) => {
        callback('DATA_RESULT');
  })
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.data).toEqual('DATA_RESULT');
});
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-callback).